# how to add the text of a label to code dom?

Tags: c#, codedom

I have a form in which there are various labels and a button..on the button click event there is a code written which generates a cs file in which i want the text of the label to be displayed..

I am trying to get the values with the help of the following function in the code dom but m not able to extract the values of the label i.e. i am just getting label1.text, label2.text, etc. instead i want the values that are there in the labels and the combobox..

can anyone please help..

`start.Statements.Add(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("Info.Valid("\"combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString()\"", "\"label1.Text\"", "\"label2.Text\"", "\"label3.Text\"", "\"numericupdown.Value.ToString()\"")");`

here start is the CodeMemberMethod to which all the statements are to be added, Info is another class and Valid is a method to which i need to pass all these values as arguments..

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, your code shouldnt extract any values because you specifies text constants. You may use string.Format method to prepare text data. Try something like below:

```
string pattern = "Info.Valid(\"\"{0}\"\", \"\"{1}\"\", \"\"{2}\"\", \"\"{3}\"\", \"\"{4}\")";
string data = string.Format(pattern,
            combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            label1.Text,
            label2.Text,
            label3.Text,
            numericupdown.Value.ToString());
start.Statements.Add(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(data));
```

For more details check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: this is giving an error "object reference not set to the instance of an object"

Comment: @user672894 Unfortunately I cant help you in this situation. Because you didnt provide code wich generates exception.

Comment: Actually i have public void AddMethod() in which i have included all the statements of the codedom when i include these two line in the same method it is giving me the error : "Object reference not set to the instance of an object" for the line : "string data = string.Format(...);"

Comment: I think you got this error because of combobox. if no item was selected, `SelectedValue` equals to null, so you cant call its ToString, just select any value from combobox before try. Ideally you should check `SelectedValue` for null before using.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help..and am sorry that i am bothering you soo much..but if i include only SelectedValue then it is working but i am not getting the value in the output and if i include SelectedValue.ToString, it is giving me this error..:|

Comment: Yes, you may apply this trick: `combobox1.SelectedValue == null ? "error" : combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Comment: But I advice you to check `SelectedValue` value beforecalling of AddMethod() and in case of null just ask user to choose value from combobox. In my opinion it would be best.